# Get an url /IP for WAMP without modifying router

Tags: url, wamp, prestashop

I have prestashop as one of the installations on WAMP. It will be nice if I can get an url or IP to show it to someone who is abroad. I am a beginner and hence not sure if I should mess with the router. I put WAMP online and used my IP, only to get into my router. Please help me present my WAMP installation of Prestashop online for a brief period. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you are going to have to make a change to your router.

One of the main functions of a router is called NAT ( Network Address Translation ). Its function is to map internal network ip addresses to requests made for resources on the internet. So your PC requests a page from stackoverflow, when the reply comes back from SO it gets routed to you PC and not one of the other PC you may be using.

A side effect of this is that it protects you from unsolicited connection from the internet, as, if you did not request a resource from ip 1.2.3.4 and it tried to get through your router the NAT layer says, hmm, nobody asked for anything from that ip and ignores the connection.

But that means that when a friend outside your network tries to get to your site it will also be refused a connection.

The way to get around this very useful and protective functionality is to `Port Forward` one or many ports on your router, specifically port 80 for a web server. This basically says that any external connection to your router from the internet using port 80 should have the connection forwarded to one specific PC inside your network i.e. the one running WAMP and Apache. If that PC is not running any service (Apache) that is listening to port 80 then nothing should happen and the external ip will get an error message. Ditto if the PC is turned off.

This site has many useful pages to help you do the port forwarding and in some cases even has documentation for your specific router. At least it will give you a better idea of what is involved.

[Port Forward.com](http://portforward.com/)

Comment: Thanks Riggs. If I use a tunneling service, can we avoid it ? If yes,point me to a good free one please.

Comment: Well you could always try using TeamViewer so you friend can connect and run your PC from his PC.